# MightyMoose - is there a way to set this up with NSpec?

Tags: continuous-testing, nspec

I am using NSpec for my BDD tests and would like to integrate MightyMoose into our project.  Can this be done? I cannot find any instructions on how to configure this.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well, but 6 weeks and no answers. I think the answer is no, since this is the first google hit.

Comment: For NSpec continuous-testing, you should try [specwatchr](http://nspec.org/continuoustesting/). It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a similar technique that NCrunch users take. Here is a link to that question:

[How do I set up NCrunch to run nspec tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117857/how-do-i-set-up-ncrunch-to-run-nspec-tests)

There are also NUnit and XUnit extensions for NSpec (essentially allowing you to tunnel NSpec tests through other testing frameworks), Mileage might vary on these extensions:

https://github.com/ddaysoftware/NSpec4NUnit

http://www.nuget.org/packages/NSpecAdapterForXunit/0.1.1

Also. Don't hesitate to reach out to us on the NSpec Github Page (we get alerts there from people that have questions).

Amir (Hacker on NSpec)